# How to change dynamically entity property's display name attribute at runtime

Tags: entity-framework, properties, entity

Entity property look like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

its for English, 
when user select another language this attribute will change at runtime

```
[Display(Name = "DisplayAnotherSomething")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```